# Google task on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have done Authentication using Google authentication API.How can I access Google task values into table view and proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *googleapi = [NSString stringWithString: @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=bank&sensor=false&key=Your_API_Key"];

NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:googleapi];
NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];
```

[For more >> Working with Google Places API in iPhone](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/07/working-with-google-places-api.html)

**Edited Addition...**

```
NSString *usergoogleapi = [NSString stringWithString:@"User_API_Key"];// change this api according to user.
NSString *googleapi = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=bank&sensor=false&key=%@",usergoogleapi];
```

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: It doesn't have authentication.My app is such a way that,what ever I changed it should be reflect on Google account task as well.

Comment: Your_API_Key is one type of authentication..without it no one can access the data. What type of change that want to reflect in google..?

Comment: Other users also allowed to enter with their google account and process the app and should reflect on google account.In this example we dont need to login.

Comment: Please check for reference gtask android app,and answer me.

Comment: Please help me guys.i have to submit this app next week!!